# Android Studio, XML, Unsupported Type

Tags: xml, android-studio

Migrating a working project from Eclipse to Android Studio, and Android Studio appears to be rejecting my resource file.  It appears Android Studio requires the xml types to be 'supported'.  Are we unable to use custom-defined xml types then?

gradle error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':sAHLibrary:mergeReleaseResources'.
> Unsupported type 'key' in file C:\Users\IV\StudioProjects\cloudsecure\sAHLibrary\src\main\res\values\key.xml
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <item type="key" name="cancelBroadcast"></item>    
</resources>
```

In this case I could make this a string or integer, but I was primarily typing it as a "key" for namespace reasons.  Is there a workaround that still allows use of custom xml types?

Answer (score 0):

Any item type is not allowed, you have to use `type="id"`, then you can access it using `R.id.cancelBroadcast`